# positive integers $n$ such that $\frac{(n^2-1)!}{(n!)^n}$ is an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

While looking to an italian Q&A site i found this question:

*Find the positive integers $0<n<50$ such that  $\frac{(n^2-1)!}{(n!)^n}$ is an integer*.

The author of the question specified that is taken by some mathematical competition. So i assume that there is a way to found the solutions in an easy way without the use of a calculator.

Given a prime number $p \le n$. The higest power of $p$ that divides $n!$ is given by $\frac{n-\sum_k a_k^{(n)}}{p-1}$, where $a_k^{(n)}$ are the digits of $n$ in base $p$ i.e.
$$
n= \sum_k a_k^{(n)} p^k
$$
(see e.g [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Factors_of_factorials)).

Comparing the prime factorization of the two factorials we have that $(n!)^n$ divides $(n^2-1)!$ if and only if, for any $p \le n$ prime
$$
1+\sum_k a_k^{(n^2-1)} \le n \sum_k a_k^{(n)}
$$
This makes possible to check if an integer is or not a solution, but checking $50$ numbers with this method doesn't look suitable for a mathematical competition, so i was wondering if there is any faster way to solve this problem.

The solutions should be (checked with Mathematica)

[image]

Comment: Didn't really try anything, but perhaps playing with $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a-kb,b)$ could work. You want $\gcd$ to be equal to denominator.

Comment: Tangential observation: the expression is $\frac{1}{n^2}\binom{n^2}{n,\cdots,n}$.

Comment: What did you notice on looking at the first $50$?  Barring error, these looked like all the composite numbers (except for $4$, oddly).

Comment: Note:  you say that "we have that $(n^2-1)! $ divides $(n!)^n$ if and only if ..." but of course you are interested in the opposite division.

Comment: @lulu you are right, it looks like any composite number except 4 is a solution (at least for small numbers)

Comment: Not all that small.  I suggest trying to prove that. Maybe start with eliminating all the primes.

Comment: FYI, I found the somewhat more general duplicate using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B(n%5E2-1)!%7D%7B(n!)%5En%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Ainteger&p=1). There are also several duplicates of your specific problem, i.e., for $n=50$, at [Prime Factorization in Variables](/q/3481467) and [For how many numbers between 1 and 50 will $\frac{(n^2 - 1)!}{n!^n}$ be an integer?](/q/3850795) (but with no answer as it was closed as a duplicate of my proposed duplicate). There are also AoPS threads, e.g., ...

Comment: (cont.) [Factorial Powers Divisibility](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c5h1781082p11735963), which states this problem is from "AMC $10$A #$25$/AMC $12$A #$24$".